# Laravel Cors Referrer Policy

Tags: laravel, nginx, referrer-policy

I run into the error below in Laravel 8 with [ChatBro](https://www.chatbro.com/en/) service when a user try to send a new message;

> Seems like the 'Referrer-Policy' of your site is 'no-referral'. For
> correct chat's work it must be equal 'no-referrer-when-downgrade' or
> any other that suits you. More information about 'Referral policy' you
> can find

Apparently, my request header is set to `Referrer Policy: no-referrer`.

The request response is;

> {"error":"Referer null or empty","type":"RefererException"}

I'm using `laravel/cors` package with the configuration below;

```php
'paths'                    => ['api/*', 'api0/*'],
'allowed_methods'          => ['*'],
'allowed_origins'.         => ['*'],
'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
'allowed_headers'          => ['*'],
'exposed_headers'          => [],
'max_age'                  => 0,
'supports_credentials'     => false,
```

How Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to define that in your Nginx server block as below;

```sh
server {
  # some configuration
  add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade";
  # other configuration
}
```

`strict-origin-when-cross-origin` is recommended over `no-referrer-when-downgrade`.

> policy that is secure, privacy-enhancing, and useful—what "useful" means depends on what you want from the referrer

More details available at [Referrer Best Practices](https://web.dev/referrer-best-practices/#why-strict-origin-when-cross-origin-(or-stricter)) and [Referrer Policy directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#directives).